# Force MySQL 4.1 return to Decimal type

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to access a MySQL 4.1 database and have problems with queries of Decimal type.  When I do a query on a single Decimal column (i.e., `SELECT amount AS v FROM Customer`) I get a `BigDecimal` through the JDBC driver, but when I do an an operation of Decimal columns (i.e., `SELECT amount + tax AS v FROM Customer`) I get a `Double` even all columns involved in the operation are Decimal.  Is there ay way in which I can Convert or Cast the result to a Decimal.  I've tried `CAST` and `CONVERT` unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1):

Some JDBC drivers allow to receive the value as several types (for example, you can call `rs.getString()`, even though the value is an `INTEGER`). Try to call `getObject()` or `getBigDecimal()` on the column and check what you get.

Comment: I'm relying on an introspection framework in which the calls are always `getObject()` and can't change that.  I would need the returning result set to come as Decimal.

Comment: In that case, `case (amount+tax as decimal(13,4)) as v` *should* work :-/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`ROUND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) function:

Quote:

> The return type is the same type as
>   that of the first argument (assuming
>   that it is integer, double, or
>   decimal).

This might work if it considers one of your columns to be the first argument, rather than the result of the expression.